# How Short IS The Arctic Summer?

Tags: seasons

In all the documentaries I've seen regarding the Arctic or anyplace close to it, like Alaska or Siberia, they simply say that summer in the Arctic is "short".

But how short is short?

How long does the sun refuse to set in the land of the midnight sun?

Comment: I find it a bit strange that you post a question here instead of *immediately* finding the answer by [doing some research yourself](https://www.google.nl/search?q=summer+in+the+arctic).

Comment: I find it a bit rude that you post a snide attitude.

Comment: It depends on how you define summer. If you mean the time between the northern hemisphere's summer solstice and autumnal equinox, that's the same everywhere, including the pole. Or do you just want to know how long the sun stays up? @JanDoggen Why link to Google Netherlands from an English-based site?

Comment: @BarryCarter  How long does the sun stay up?

Comment: You can use http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/RS_OneYear.php to compute this. For 2016, the sun rises on March 18th at 0158, and sets at 1731 on September 24th.

Comment: @Barry I missed that one, it is my deafult.